# How do you get syncErrors out of state using redux-form selectors

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

So I have a redux-form component that has a validate function that returns values with the Field...

```
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {
    orderHeader: {}
  };

  const orderHeader = values.orderHeader || {};
  if (!orderHeader.orderID) {
    errors.orderHeader.orderID = "Working";
  }
  if (!orderHeader.salesRepID) {
    errors.orderHeader.salesRepID = "Working as well";
  }

  return errors;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use a selector to return all of the syncError values to an Error manifest component that will list all current errors.

My selector looks like this

```
const selector = formValueSelector('mainForm')
MainForm = connect(
  state =>
  ({
    syncErrors: getFormSyncErrors('mainForm')(state),
    initialValues: state.account.data,
  }
),
  { load: loadAccount }, // bind account loading action creator
)(MainForm);
```

logging the following returns undefined...

```
  render() {
    const { error, handleSubmit, load, pristine, reset, submitting, values, syncErrors } = this.props;
    console.log(syncErrors)
```

I feel like I'm making a syntax mistake as I would expect this to return the syncErrors section of state as an object... It appears in state correctly under form.mainForm.syncErrors.

Am I completely misunderstanding this? What would be helpful for me to provide?

Here is the component in its entirety...

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Row, Col, Container, Form } from 'reactstrap';
import classnames from 'classnames'
import store from "../../../store";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import axios from 'axios'
import RemoteSubmitButton from '../../ReduxForms/RemoteSubmitButton'
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector, getFormSyncErrors } from 'redux-form';
import { load as loadAccount } from '../../../reducers/account';
import renderInput from '../../ReduxForms/FormComponents';
import submit from '../../ReduxForms/submit'
//import validate from '../../ReduxForms/validate'

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {
    orderHeader: {}
  };

  const orderHeader = values.orderHeader || {};
  if (!orderHeader.orderID) {
    errors.orderHeader.orderID = "Working";
  }
  if (!orderHeader.salesRepID) {
    errors.orderHeader.salesRepID = "Working as well";
  }

  return errors;
}
const remotejson= "SalesObject.json";

class MainForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    data: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
  axios.get('/data/' + remotejson)
    .then((response) => {
    //    console.log(response.data);
       this.setState({data: response.data})
     })
    .catch((error)=>{
       //console.log(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { error, handleSubmit, load, pristine, reset, submitting, values, syncErrors } = this.props;
    console.log({syncErrors})
    return (
        <div style={{ padding: 15 }}>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => load(this.state.data)}>Load Order</button>
            <Container>
              <Row>
                <Col sm={4}>
                  <Field label="order ID" id="orderID" name="orderHeader.orderID" type="text" component={renderInput} />
                </Col>
                <Col sm={4}>
                  <Field id="salesRepID" name="orderHeader.salesRepID" type="text" component={renderInput} />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Container>
            {syncErrors && <strong>{syncErrors}</strong>}
            {error && <strong>{error}</strong>}
          </Form>
          <RemoteSubmitButton />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

    // Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
let MainReduxForm = MainForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'mainForm', // a unique identifier for this form
  enableReinitialize: true, // Important after the data load process is moved to redux saga. This should allow for a common sales object to be built
  validate,
  onSubmit: submit // submit function must be passed to onSubmit
})(MainForm);

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
const selector = formValueSelector('mainForm')
MainReduxForm = connect(
  state =>
  ({
    syncErrors: getFormSyncErrors('mainForm')(state),
    initialValues: state.account.data
  }),
  { load: loadAccount }, // bind account loading action creator
)(MainReduxForm);

export default MainReduxForm;
```

Comment: Can you post the code with the component, so that its easy to figure out the error

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri please let me know if you would want to see anything else besides the main component which I've added above. The submit component just returns an alert with the serialized object, and load is working as expected.... I think that my mistake is in not understanding how the selector returns data. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you try two things, use a different name for assigning like

`let MainReduxForm = MainForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'mainForm', // a unique identifier for this form
  enableReinitialize: true, 
  validate,
  onSubmit: submit 
})(MainForm);`

and then 

`MainReduxForm = connect(
  state =>
  ({
    syncErrors: getFormSyncErrors('mainForm')(state),
    initialValues: state.account.data
  }),
  { load: loadAccount }, // bind account loading action creator
)(MainReduxForm);`

Comment: I changed the assignment names and its still returning undefined. I updated the code in the original question too incase I missed anything from your comment. Thanks!

Comment: What you missed is `export default MainForm;`, you would need to change it to `export default MainReduxForm;`

Comment: updated... Still returning undefined in the console.log.... edited the code again just incase anyone comes across this same issue.

Comment: I seems I found out the errors in your got

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`syncErrors` is a keyword that is internally used by redux-form and is not made available as a prop to the form component. You need to pass your syncError to the component with a different name

```
class MainForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    data: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
  axios.get('/data/' + remotejson)
    .then((response) => {
    //    console.log(response.data);
       this.setState({data: response.data})
     })
    .catch((error)=>{
       //console.log(error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { error, handleSubmit, load, pristine, reset, submitting, values, synchronousError } = this.props;
    console.log({syncErrors})
    return (
        <div style={{ padding: 15 }}>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => load(this.state.data)}>Load Order</button>
            <Container>
              <Row>
                <Col sm={4}>
                  <Field label="order ID" id="orderID" name="orderHeader.orderID" type="text" component={renderInput} />
                </Col>
                <Col sm={4}>
                  <Field id="salesRepID" name="orderHeader.salesRepID" type="text" component={renderInput} />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </Container>
            {synchronousError && <strong>{synchronousError}</strong>}
            {error && <strong>{error}</strong>}
          </Form>
          <RemoteSubmitButton />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

    // Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
let MainReduxForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'mainForm', // a unique identifier for this form
  enableReinitialize: true, // Important after the data load process is moved to redux saga. This should allow for a common sales object to be built
  validate,
  onSubmit: submit // submit function must be passed to onSubmit
})(MainForm);

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
const selector = formValueSelector('mainForm')
MainReduxForm = connect(
  state =>
  ({
    synchronousError : getFormSyncErrors('mainForm')(state), // change name here
    initialValues: state.account.data
  }),
  { load: loadAccount }, // bind account loading action creator
)(MainReduxForm);

export default MainReduxForm;
```

I made a **[demo working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qx3kky64w6)** too

Comment: You are my hero! That has been driving me CRAZY for days!

Comment: @ShawnMatthews, well its one hell of a bug to figure it out. I came across it while I was experimenting with the sandbox I provided